# isMetaDown method not working in java SE 14 for handling mouse event

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

Body of class that extends JFrame

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MouseDetailsFrame extends JFrame {

    private final JLabel statusJLabel;

    public MouseDetailsFrame() {
        super("Mouse Adapter example");
        statusJLabel = new JLabel("You clicked 0 times");
        add(statusJLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapterHandler());

    }

    private class MouseAdapterHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            int posX = event.getX();
            int posY = event.getY();
            String details = String.format("You clicked %d time(s) ", event.getClickCount());

            if (event.isMetaDown() == true)
                details += "with Right Mouse Button";

            else if (event.isAltDown() == true)
                details += "with center Mouse Button";

            else
                details += "with Left Mouse Button";

            statusJLabel.setText(details + String.format(" at ( %d, %d )", posX, posY));
        }
    }
}
```

Driver class containing main method:

```
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MouseEventTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {

                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {

                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MouseDetailsFrame mouseDetailsFrame = new MouseDetailsFrame();
        mouseDetailsFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mouseDetailsFrame.setSize(400, 200);
        mouseDetailsFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Whenever I press any mouse button the program registers only as a Left button.
However, the center mouse button can be simulated by pressing left mouse button while holding alt key.
I don't quite understand, I have a 3 button mouse, doesn't pressing each button causes JVM to generate different mouse events?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a 3 button mouse, doesn't pressing each button causes JVM to generate different mouse events?*

Maybe you are looking for:

1. `SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(event)`
2. `SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(event)`
3. `SwingUtilities.isRightButton(event)`

Comment: So, what is the use of isAltDown() and isMetaDown() ?

Comment: You use them in combination to see if the mouse was clicked AND the Alt key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

In older Java versions `event.isAltDown()` returns true if the Alt key is pressed or if the middle button is pressed, [this is a bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6495530).
In newer versions, like Java 14, it returns true only if the Alt key is pressed.

The same bug affects `event.isMetaDown()` but with the right mouse button.

In other words, `event.isAltDown()` and `event.isMetaDown()` should not be used to test for mouse buttons